# Looking for skeleton or polygon offset algorithm in R

Tags: r, skeletal-mesh

I found some useful links in this SO question  [An algorithm for inflating/deflating (offsetting, buffering) polygons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1109536/an-algorithm-for-inflating-deflating-offsetting-buffering-polygons) .
Sorry - no 'net access so `sos` doesn't work, so does anyone have an implementation of the skeleton algorithm in R?

Edit: I would like to generate deflated polygons as in the StackOverflow link (top image); or as seen on http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Straight_skeleton .

Comment: @Josh - thanks for the pointer.  If I can figure out how to squoosh my vertex data into an `sp` object I'll report back on how that works.

Comment: @JoshO'Brien   Sadly,  `gBuffer` "fills in" the polygon, turning it into a puffy cloud sort of thing.

Comment: How do you post this on stack overflow with no net access?

Comment: Am having trouble knowing what you are after with no example data or images. Maybe you could at least indicate which of the answers/images in the link you provided does what you want. (I still think `gBuffer()` might be what you're after. Did you explore the `joinStyle` and `mitreLimit` arguments (to get 'non-puffy' corners for the buffered areas), and did you try setting `width` to a negative value to "deflate" the polygon(s))?

Comment: @Spacedman I should clarify that I have basic proxy net access, but cannot send general requests out the way `sos` does.

Comment: @JoshO'Brien I will continue playing w/ those parameters to see what happens.

Comment: @JoshO'Brien  It turns out my mistake was in the magnitude of `width` . Once I made it a small enough fraction of my current plot size, things look very good indeed.  Go ahead and post your answer so I can check it off.  (Tho' I must say it's a bit of a pain to turn a N-by-2 `matrix` into a `SpatialPolygons sp` object. I think I need to coerce twice with `bar<- as(my.matrix,'gpc.poly')` followed by `foo<-as(bar,'SpatialPolygons')` . In any case, thanks again for the solution.

Comment: OK, just added an answer. Frankly, the more useful part of it may be the utility function `xy2SP()`, which I have posted before [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16553497/calculating-the-area-of-a-confidence-ellipse-in-a-certain-region-of-space). As you say, creating a SpatialPolygons object in the first place is an unfortunate pain in the ***.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft sos only uses basic http requests, and you can configure R to use a proxy.

Comment: @Spacedman in theory yes, in practice the corp firewall (in concert with Websense) blocks something-or-other and I cannot make contact with the locations that `???foo` is trying to reach.  I've spent a lot of time fiddling w/ proxy/noproxy settings for R and no go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`gBuffer()`, from the elegant and powerful **rgeos** package accepts negative values in its `width` argument, returning `SpatialPolygons` that are 'shrunk' by the given amount.

```
library(sp)
library(rgeos)

## Create a SpatialPolygons object from set of x-y coordinates (the hard part!)
xy2SP <- function(xy, ID=NULL) {
    if(is.null(ID)) ID <- sample(1e12, size=1)
    SpatialPolygons(list(Polygons(list(Polygon(xy)), ID=ID)),
                    proj4string=CRS("+proj=merc"))
}
xy <- data.frame(x=c(0,2,3,1,0), y=c(0,0,2,2,0))
SP <- xy2SP(xy)

## Shrink the SpatialPolygons object by supplying a negative width to gBuffer()
plot(SP)
plot(gBuffer(SP, width=-0.2), add=TRUE, border="red")
```

[image]